# Existence of rational points on non-singular plane cubic projective curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I want to learn some algebraic geometry, also in concrete examples.
That's were my question comes from.

Let $X$ be a non-singular plane cubic projective curve over $\mathbb Q$. I wonder about the following:

(Q1) Are there methods to determine, for special families of such $X$, whether there is a rational point on $X$?

(Q2) Are there families of equations for which it is known that the corresponding $X$ has a rational point?

(Q3) Are there references about the existence of rational points on such $X$?

In the books I know, e.g., Silverman/Tate or Husemöller, the authors say something like: "We will ignore this difficult problem and assume that $X$ always has a rational point."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are looking for is called "Descent". Chapter 10 of Silverman's book gives an introduction.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific. When looking into Chapter 10 of Silverman's book (I suppose you mean "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"), it doesn't look like results on the existence of rational points. But I really don't know much about the topic.

Comment: In general to any curve $C/\mathbb{Q}$ you can associate an abelian variety called the Jacobian of $C$ to it. When $C$ has genus $1$ this abelian variety is an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, which becomes isomorphic to $C$ over the algebraic closure. There is a morphism $C \to E$ and in your specific case the morphism will have degree $9$. If $C$ has a local obstruction then disregard it, otherwise $C$ defines an element of the Selmer group of $E$ and has a point if and only if this element comes from a point in $E(\mathbb{Q})/3E(\mathbb{Q})$. Determining in families is harder.

Comment: For Q2... take any Weierstrass equation